# Append lines with perl

Tags: perl

My input lines:

```
Movies: Action
Adventure
Biography
Comedy
Books:
Biography
Romance
Sci-Fi
War
```

My problem (implemented in Perl): check what a line looks like, and if it ends with ":" append the next line to it.

In my example, it joins the line that contain "Books:" to the line that contain "Biography", but this is only one example - the contents of lines may differ in many ways.

```
Movies: Action
Adventure
Biography
Comedy
Books: Biography
Romance
Sci-Fi
War
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A look-behind assertion can be used:

```
s/(?<=:)\s*\n/ /gs;
```

Comment: *[sidyll](http://stackoverflow.com/users/557306/sidyll)*: Thank you. I do not know either. :-)

Comment: The -1 is for superfluous use of the **s** flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
perl -pe 's/\r?\n$/ / if(/:\s*$/)' file
```

or

```
perl -pe 'chomp if(/:\s*$/)' file
```

if you are okay with not having a space after `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a little program to work on your input:

```
while (<>) {
  s/\s+$/ / if /:$/;
  print;
}
```

As the structure is exactly what the `-p` option provides, you can do it in one line from your shell:

```
perl -pe 's/\s*/ / if /:$/' text_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `$text =~ s/:\s*\n/: /msg;`